# React-native open piker when I click on an Image

Tags: react-native, menu, icons, instagram, picker

I'm looking for a way to open pickers when I click on an image or icon. Like in Instagram.

[picker menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kaugy.jpg)

Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **[model](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal.html)** to open dialog like this.

Here is small example for it:

modeljs.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, Modal } from 'react-native';


export default class Modeljs extends Component {

  render() {
const { onPressCancel, onPressReport, visible } = this.props;

    return (
      <Modal
        animationType={'fade'}
        transparent
        visible={visible}
        onRequestClose={() => { }}
      >
        <View
          style={{ flex: 1,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
          }}
        >
          <Text>You are in Model</Text>
        </View>
      </Modal>);
  }
}
```

You can use modeljs in your screen like this:

```
      state ={
        modalVisible: false,
        seletData: [],
      }
      setModalVisible(visible) {
        this.setState({ modalVisible: visible });
      }
      modelPress(item) {
        this.state = { ...this.state, seletData: item };
        this.setModalVisible(true);
      }
      renderReportDialog() {
        return (
          <Modeljs
            visible={this.state.modalVisible}
            onPressCancel={() => { this.setModalVisible(false); }}
onPressReport={()=>{alert('Called')}}
            modelPress={(data) => {
              this.setModalVisible(false);
            }}
          />);
      }
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer, I did exactly what you said, but i got this error

Comment: Can you give me your error? As I already implemented above in one of my application.

Comment: Thank's for your answer, I did exactly what you said, but i got this error :
"undefined is not a function (evaluating 'inst.render()')

Comment: I think its due to mismatch of class name. I update it. Can you take new code and use it.

Comment: It's better, but I still have an error :"Can't find variable: visible" in modal.js line 10. I don't understand why...

Comment: Its props which we passing from a parent class. Check render method of modeljs.

Comment: Anyone can you please show me how to implement onPressReport? How to get the pressed item in modal?

Comment: We need to add one more method while calling it.

Comment: Can  you tell me how to implement this method in Modaljs?

Comment: We can put this.props.onPressReport() from Modal.js and it will call back to main screen